# Recursively iterate though a file system in drive?

Tags: python, recursion, google-drive-api

I am trying to recursively iterate through a folder named "users" which is stored in my drive. 
the file looks something like this

```
>Users
  >1 
    >1.json
  >2
    >2.json
  >3
    >3.json
```

I have written a recursive program that will identify if the mimeType is a folder.If it's not a folder then it stores the content in a variable called `response` and if it's a folder then it recursively calls itself.

```
def start_printing(user_fld_id, service):
    flow_of_file = service.files().list(q=" '{0}' in parents ".format(user_fld_id),spaces ='drive').execute()

    for item in flow_of_file['files']:  

        if item['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
            print('Name of File is: {0} of type: {1}'.format(item['name'],item['mimeType']))
            folder_name = item['name']
            folder_id = item['id']
            user_fld_id = folder_id
            start_printing(user_fld_id, service)
        else:
            print(u'This is content with name =  {0} for folder {1} with ID {2}'.format(item['name'],folder_name, item['id']))
            file_id_number = item['id']
            response = service.files().get_media(fileId = file_id_number).execute()
            send_to_another_function(response, folder_name)
```

My task is to send the `response` variable along with the folder name  where my current file is residing. According to my program I am not able to store the value of folder name in later loops.

How do I solve this issue? I am open for new solutions as well!

Thank you

Comment: So what you want is to get the folder name (and the folder above) that the file is in?

Comment: yes! if file name is 1.json I want to pass 1 , 1json as parameters. And if there are multiple json files then (1, 1,json) in first loop , (1, 2.json) in second loop like that

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. I could understand that `>1.json` of `>Users\n  >1 \n    >1.json` is the filename (`1.json`). What is `>1` of `>Users\n  >1 \n    >1.json`? 2. What result do you want? Can you provide the sample result you expect?

Comment: So, I basically need to send parameters such as the parent folder name( in this case is 1, 2 , 3) , ad the response variable that stores the data of the json file.
Ex:
1st loop 
return (1, json_data)
2nd loop
return (2,json_data)

Another question is that what if I have miltiple files in each folder( multiple json files) in my 1st outerloop and 1st inner loop I can retrieve the parent foler name but in 1st outer loop and 2nd inner loop I loose the parent folder name.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most obvious solution is to store the previous folders as an input array.

Add one parameter to you `start_printing` function. And populate it as you iterate through folders like so.

```py
def start_printing(user_fld_id, service, previous_folders=[]):
    flow_of_file = service.files().list(q=" '{0}' in parents ".format(user_fld_id),spaces ='drive').execute()

    for item in flow_of_file['files']:  

        if item['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
            print('Name of File is: {0} of type: {1}'.format(item['name'],item['mimeType']))
            folder_name = item['name']
            folder_id = item['id']
            user_fld_id = folder_id
            start_printing(user_fld_id, 
                           service,
                           previous_folders=previous_folders+[item])    # Added line     
        else:
            print(u'This is content with name =  {0} for folder {1} with ID {2}'.format(item['name'],folder_name, item['id']))
            file_id_number = item['id']
            response = service.files().get_media(fileId = file_id_number).execute()
            send_to_another_function(response, folder_name)
```

So then you can actually access to this array in subsequent call. In this case the last element of this array would be the right above folder.

You could alternative retrieve the folder each time through the `parents` attribute of the `item` variable. But having actually made those request before would be retrieving the same information twice.